# What is the sum of all $k$ values?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> In an urn there are a certain number (at least two) of black marbles and a certain number of white
>   marbles. Steven blindfolds himself and chooses two marbles from the urn at random. Suppose the
>   probability that the two marbles are of opposite color is $\frac{1}{2}$
>   . Let $k_1 < k_2 < · · · < k_{100}$ be the $100$
>   smallest possible values for the total number of marbles in the urn. Compute the remainder when
>   $k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + · · · + k_{100}$
>   is divided by $1000$.

Let $P(B)$ be probability that a black marble is chosen. let $P(W)$ be the probability a white marble is chosen.

$$P(B) \cdot P(W) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Let there be $n$ total marbles, $x$ black, $y$ white marbles.

$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{xy}{\binom{n}{2}} = \frac{2xy}{n(n-1)}$$

Because $x \ge 2$, $n(n-1) \ge 4$, so $n(n-1) = 4$ is the least and $n(n-1) = 104$ is the maximum.

The solution for a $c$ is:

$$n^2 - n - c = 0 \implies n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4c}}{2}$$

Now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Remember that $y = n-x$. So you get the equation $n(n-1) = 4 x(n-x)$. That gives you some constraints on $n$.

Comment: What is $c$?  Clearly $n(n-1)=104$ is not the maximum, as that says $n \le 10$ and there will not be $100$ values for $n$  You can solve Daniel Fischer's equation as a quadratic for either variable, then need to choose $x$ or $n$ values that make the discriminant an integer

Comment: @RossMillikan, the ultimate goal though is to find the $n$ values though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out in a comment, with $y=n-x$ your equation becomes $n(n-1)=4x(n-x)$. Intuitively, one might expect that the probability is $1/2$ if roughly half of the marbles are white and half are black, i.e. if $x\simeq n/2$. So let's set $x=(n+\delta)/2$. Then

$$n(n-1)=4\frac{n+\delta}2\left(n-\frac{n+\delta}2\right)=n^2-\delta^2\;,$$

so $n=\delta^2$. For $x$ to be an integer, we needed $\delta$ to be an integer of the same parity as $n$, and this solution indeed gives them the same parity, so each integer $\delta\gt1$ yields a solution. All that's left to do is to sum the first $101$ squares and subtract $1$.